# How to get the text of the selected option of a select using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have this select:

```
     <select id="days">
        <option value="0">Today</option>
        <option value="1">Yesterday</option>
        <option value="7">Last week</option>
     </select>
```

and someone selects the 3rd option 'last week', I can get the value of last week (which is 7), using `$("#days").val()`, but how can I get the value of the text i.e 'Last week'?

Comment: I know this question has been asked before, but I can't find it...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$("#days option:selected").text()
```

Answer (score 3):

Does .text() not give you the result you are after?

http://marcgrabanski.com/article/jquery-select-list-values - found this too

Comment: I tried `.text()` too, but it gives me a string containing all the the options, not just the selected one

Comment: ah yes, you do need to use like najmeddine suggests and make sure you only get the selected item

Answer (score 0):

Add a class "myOption" to the options, and an sttribute value with the text you want. Then:

> $(".myOption").each( function( i ) { if( $(this).attr('selected') ) { $(this).attr('value') } );

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little verbose (I'm *sure* I can remember an easier way...)

```
var value = $("#days").val(); 
$("option[value='" + value + "']", "#days").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using:

```
var s = $("#days");
var i = s.prop("selectedIndex"); //get selected indexs
s.children().eq(i).text();
```