# Detect HTML Option Value Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the text of the selected option of a select using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391019/how-to-get-the-text-of-the-selected-option-of-a-select-using-jquery)

I have the following script:

```
<select id = "people">
<option value = "0">Choose</option>
<option value = "1">John</option>
<option value = "2">David</option>
</select>
```

How Can I use jQuery to detect the value of the option that is currently selected?

i.e. (pseudo-ish code)

```
if(people.option.text == "Choose"){
   //Alert - Please make a selection
}else{
   //Valid - do something
}
```

EDIT: code not working

```
  echo("<script>");
  echo("$(document).ready(function(){");
  echo("$(\"#go\").click(function(e){");
  echo("var selText = $(\"#people option:selected\").text();");
  echo("if(selText == \"Choose\"){");

  echo("}else{");
  echo("window.location.href = \"viewprofile.php\";");
  echo("}");
  echo("});");
  echo("});");
  echo("</script>");
```

It constantly triggers the else statement and navigates away...

EDIT: Got it working -> changed .text() and val()

Comment: First of all, your `value` attribute value should be enclosed in double quotes like that: `<option value="0">Choose</option>`

Comment: sorry it's a typo - typed it off the fly

Comment: There is not reason whatsoever to use `echo` here. Just put the markup/JS code in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example looks like you want to get the selected **text**, not value.

So have this:

```
var selText = $("#people option:selected").text();
if(selText == "Choose") {
   //Alert - Please make a selection
} else {
   //Valid - do something
}
```

To get selected value and check it, have such code:

```
var selValue = parseInt($("#people").val(), 10);
if (selValue == 0) {
    //Alert - Please make a selection
} else {
    //Valid - do something
}
```

Comment: This is what I want! I'm trying this but to no avail..I have updated my code. The only difference is I'm using php to write the HTML - but this shouldn;t affect matters

Comment: Can you look at my edit->my code always seems to fire the else statement...

Comment: When you add `alert('selected text: ' + selText);` what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#people [value!=0]:selected').length > 0){
    //selected
} else {
    //not selected
}
```

Comment: but my default option is "choose" so that won't work

Comment: That's not shown in your html though. Edited answer

Comment: It is--> <option value = "0">Choose</option>...

Comment: NO ITS NOT - you are not showing which element is selected. You say 'my default option is choose'. Your code doesn't show that. The current (default) selected option *should* be shown by selected="selected".

Comment: @kissmyface: If no option is marked as selected, by default, the first one is selected.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            if($(this).text()=="Choose") ...
            else ...
        });
```

Comment: I need to detect whether the selected value is equal to 'choose'...so just a simple if/else that checks the selected value

Answer (score 0):

```
if (jQuery('#people option:selected').val()=="Choose"){
}
else{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value that is selected using [val](http://api.jquery.com/val), then take the appropriate action.  Shown below in a form submission handler to prevent form submission.  You might also want to consider using the [validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) plugin for this particular case, making the field required, and having the default option have no value.

```
$(function() {
   $('form').submit( function() {
       var selectedPerson = $('#people').val();
       if (!selectedPerson || selectedPerson == '0') {
          alert('you must choose an option for people');
          return false;
       }
       // continue form validation and submission
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `value` of the selected `<option>`, use:

```
$('select').val()
```

To get the HTML content of the selected `<option>`, use:

```
$'select :selected').html()
```

And to check if a certain `<option>` is selected, use:

```
if ($('option').is(':selected')) ...
```