# How to get the text of the selected value of a dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery get specific option tag text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text)
>   [How to get the text of the selected option of a select using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391019/how-to-get-the-text-of-the-selected-option-of-a-select-using-jquery)

I have a dropdown list and I want to know the text of the selected item. For example:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="2">Saab</option>
    <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
</select>
```

If I know the selected value, how can I get it's text value? For instance, if the value is `1` how can I get `Volvo`?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `option:selected` to get the chosen option of the `select` element, then the `text()` method:

```
$("select option:selected").text();
```

Here's an example:

```js
console.log($("select option:selected").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Saab</option>
    <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Then you can add links to each jQuery function in the docs... Anyway I dislike the way it's done in his edit. It can be simpler with `$("select).val()`. as I said, up to you. and +1 by the way.

Comment: ok i coded `alert($("#presetname-"+rname+" option:selected").text());​` but it has an error. Any idea why it is not working..?

Comment: What's the error, and what value does `rname` have?

Comment: it says `illegal character`. `rname` is just a string value.

Comment: Works fine thanks.

Answer (score 15):

```
$("#select_id").find("option:selected").text();
```

It is helpful if your control is on Server side. In *.NET* it looks like:

```
$('#<%= dropdownID.ClientID %>').find("option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you are having dropdownlist like this

```
<select id="testID">
<option value="1">Value1</option>
<option value="2">Value2</option>
<option value="3">Value3</option>
<option value="4">Value4</option>
<option value="5">Value5</option>
<option value="6">Value6</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Get dropdown selected Value" onclick="getHTML();">
```

after giving id to dropdownlist you just need to add jquery code like this

```
function getHTML()
{
      var display=$('#testID option:selected').html();
      alert(display);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is through css3 `$("select option:selected")` and then use the `.text()` or `.html()` function. depending on what you want to have.

Comment: CSS3? Where does that come into it?

Comment: Indeed, `:selected` is not CSS3, it's one of the jQuery selector enhancments.

Comment: _"Because `:selected` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:selected` cannot ... ..."_ [source](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Comment: oh thanks for this correction! i thought :selected and :checked are css3 pseudo classes. And i know that jquery is just [borrowing](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) css selectors :)