# ASP.NET AJAX Controls and Toolkit textbox autocomplete with if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm using ASP.NET AJAX Controls and Toolkit to autocomplete a `TextBox` in a .aspx page. The `TextBox` works as a search field in connection with a dropdown. Now I only want the autocomplete to show when a certain category from the dropdown is selected.

For autocomplete I've got this code

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static string[] DepartmentAuto(string prefixText, int count)
{
  
        string[] _strArray = {  "Factory Management", "Housekeeping", "HR", "Industry Development"}

        return _strArray;

    
}
```

And my dropdown/ textbox works like this

```
void Filter()
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Title")
    {

        ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Title LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' ";

    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Department")
    {

        ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Department LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' ";

    }
}
```

I've tried to add the if statement to my autocomplete code like this

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static string[] DepartmentAuto(string prefixText, int count)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Department")
    {
         string[] _strArray = {  "Factory Management", "Housekeeping", "HR", "Industry Development"}

        return _strArray;


    }

}
```

But then I get two errors-

> DepartmenAuto: not all code paths return a value
>
> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property "DropdownList1"

Any help how I can do this?

Comment: The errors are self explanatory #1 you are returning an array string only in if statement, what if your condition is not met. #2 you cannot use instance elements in static method i.e. your dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

***DepartmenAuto: not all code paths return a value***

- This is because your `return` statement is now surrounded by the `if` block and hence the compiler wont be able to know what to return if your code doesnt go into the `if` block. So either you remove the `if` condition like previously you had or your give another `return` statement outside those curly braces.

***An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property "DropdownList1"***

- *This is because you cant use a control in a static method.* *You can only access static everything inside static anything.* So you have to come around with something else for check on the dropdown. I suggest you go on and have a check on the `JQuery` side for this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. Any suggestion on how I could go about it with jQuery?

Comment: See these links : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411568/how-to-get-the-text-of-the-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-list

Comment: Once you check with JQuery, you can return true or false as per that and then make a postback. Otherwise if isn't your expected value, no need to even make a postback.