# How to get the value of a selected option of a pull down menu using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
  <select id="testSelection">
           <option> test1 </option> 
           <option> test2 </option> 
           <option> test3 </option> 
           <option> test4 </option> <--- selected this one from the pull down menu 
           <option> test5 </option> 
           <option> test6 </option> 
  </select>

             $("#testSelection").change(function()
             {
                    alert($(this).text());
             });
```

Strange to me, the alert message shows all the selections but I was expecting it to show on only test4 text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the text of the selected option of a select using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391019/how-to-get-the-text-of-the-selected-option-of-a-select-using-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<select id="testSelection">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    .....
</select>
```

It really depends on what you want:

```
$("#testSelection").on('change', function() {
    // if you just want the text/html inside the select (ie: test1, test2, etc)
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').text()); 

    // or you want the actual value of the option <option value="THISHERE">
    alert($(this).val()); 
});​
```

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XCSgG/5/)

Comment: This is false, both methods return the value="" of the selected item. This is what you wanted to show I believe: http://jsfiddle.net/XCSgG/4/. The first val() should be text() to return the text of the selected value. The second val() will return the value of the select menu.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that! Put them in backwards like a dummy (also accidentally typed .val() up for the :selected one)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `val()` function, not the `text()` function.

```
$("#testSelection").change(function()
{
    alert($(this).val());
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).text()` returns all the text within the element, in this case, the `select` element. That's why you get `"test1 test2 ..."`.

Assuming you want the text of the selected option:

```
$(this).find(':selected').text()
```

If you want the value attribute of the selected option, then @mcpDESIGNS' answer will work. However, note that you need to add `value` attributes to your `option` elements, like so:

```
<option value="test4">test4</option>
```