# how to print selected values from multiselect dropdown list using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Multi-select</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="example" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<script>
  $('#example').multiselect({
    buttonClass: "btn btn-default",
    buttonWidth: "140px",
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my code...i have to print selected values from dropdownlist...how can i use jquery...if i select 1,2,3 options it will print that values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the text of the selected option of a select using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391019/how-to-get-the-text-of-the-selected-option-of-a-select-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.val()` along with select element selector:

> When the first element in the collection is a select-multiple (i.e., a select element with the multiple attribute set), it returns an array containing the value of each selected option, or null if no options are selected.

```
$('#example').val();
```

You can convert this array to CSV using `.join()`.

Comment: can i use this code var values=$('#example').val() ??

Comment: `$('#example').val().join(',')`

Comment: is it possible to acess this values into another html file??

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();
```